# Filling a pandas series with missing periodIndex values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

Given a pandas series with a PeriodIndex, which has some missing values, how 
does one fill in missing periods, with value 0.

**Example:**

```py
import pandas as pd

index = pd.PeriodIndex(['2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-04'], freq='M')
series = pd.Series([1, 1, 1], index=index)

# Do some magic with the series
```

Series should now be:

```
'2019-01' 1
'2019-02' 1
'2019-03' 0
'2019-04' 1
```

**What I've tried:**

I've tried using `resample('M').fillna()`, but found the new options on `fillna()` don't include filling with 0, and unlike previous questions I've found on stackoverflow, I'm using a later version of pandas, where `fill_method` is no longer available.

I've also tried reindexing with the index from the series itself, but this still appears to leave holes.

**Context:**
In case this is a case of "you're just doing it the wrong way!" I thought I'd some context. I'm using a series with a periodindex to model a predicted cashflow for a loan, and calling numpy.irr on the series to calculate it's rate of return. Unfortunately, numpy irr is unaware of indices, so I need to convert the loan into a full array, where empty months are given by 0 values, but there are always 12 values per year.

I'm open to hearing other methods of calculating this - with libraries, or DateTimeIndex or any other methods.

Comment: Whats wrong with `series.resample('M').sum().fillna(0)`. It gives exactly the output you want?

Comment: why does .sum() work? I tried and it does, but what is the logic?

Comment: In this case it just returns the value of the day, since we use the same frequency `M`. If you would go from daily to monthly, it would sum up the values.

Comment: @Erfan thank you, this did solve the problem. If possible, could you elaborate on why this works / why fillna() cannot be called without first calling sum()?